# Is there a way to condense variable assignments?

Tags: java

I was just wondering if there's a way to combine some of these statements. I believe there's a way to assign two things at once, I'm just having trouble remembering the syntax.

```
    // Selects two cards for the player.
    choosePlayerFirstNumber = r.nextInt(12);
    choosePlayerFirstSuit = r.nextInt(3);
    choosePlayerSecondNumber = r.nextInt(12);
    choosePlayerSecondSuit = r.nextInt(3);
    

    // Selects two cards for the dealer.
    chooseDealerFirstNumber = r.nextInt(12);
    chooseDealerFirstSuit = r.nextInt(3);
    chooseDealerSecondNumber = r.nextInt(12);
    chooseDealerSecondSuit = r.nextInt(3);


    suits = new String[]{"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};
    number = new String[]{"An Ace", "A 2", "A 3", "A 4", "A 6", "A 7", "An 8", "A 9", "A 10", "A Jack", "A Queen", "A King"};
```

Comment: The suggestion from @NicoVanBelle might be what you asked for, but it might not be what you want. Your code and the suggestion are not equivalent! In your code the call to ``Random.nextInt` is really called twice.

Comment: This code allows selection of the same cards/suits several times.  You should create objects representing a card and a deck of cards, shuffle the deck and pick the cards from the deck.

Comment: Avoid [magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47882). Instead of `choosePlayerFirstNumber = r.nextInt(12);` clearer code would probably be `choosePlayerFirstNumber = r.nextInt(allNumbers.size());` (which brings second suggestion, rename `number` to something like `allNumbers`). This will probably also prevent you from making mistakes like `r.nextInt(3);` which will never let you get `Spades`.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to notice is that you need two information to point to a card: Its suit and its value. So that could be a class, like this:

```java
class Card {
  int value;
  int suit;
}
```

You could then create a player which is holding two cards:

```java
class Player {
  Card first, second;
}
```

Now you need to assign the randomness, but beware that what you did is not realistic in a card-play setup, you can have multiple cards with the same value and same suit! So you might want to create a list with all possible cards and randomly draw from that for added realism.

If you don't care about this detail, you can simply assign the values in the constructor.

```java
public class Card {
  private static Random r=new Random();
  public Card(){
    this.value=r.nextInt(12);
    this.suit=r.nextInt(4);
  }
  public final int value;
  public final int suit;
}
```

And then you can create the cards when you create the player object:

```java
public class Player {
  public Player(){
    first=new Card();
    second=new Card();
  }
  public final Card first, second;
}
```